# Android browsers not handling touchmove events correctly

Tags: javascript, android, touch, touchmove

When I try to inspect the `touchmove` event in [**this jsbin demo**](http://jsbin.com/popiq/1/) it only triggers once in Chrome and Opera for Android, and immediately after that, it triggers a `touchcancel` event, instead of continuing to trigger `touchmove` events?

Based on both [**the W3C specs**](http://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/#the-touchmove-event), and the behaviour of the `touchmove` event in both Firefox for Android and Android's default browser, it seems to me that the way the touch events are supposed to work is that the `touchmove` event keeps triggering while the touch is still on the page. After [trying to test in this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/popiq/1/) though, I got the following log messages:

```
touchstart event; starting on (140,197) on the screen, or (381,536) on the page.
touchend event; starting on (undefined,undefined) on the screen, or (undefined,undefined) on the page.
touchstart event; starting on (181,137) on the screen, or (492,372) on the page.
touchmove event; starting on (182,153) on the screen, or (495,416) on the page.
touchcancel event; starting on (undefined,undefined) on the screen, or (undefined,undefined) on the page.
```

This is what happened when I first tapped the screen (shown via a `touchstart` and `touchend`), and then dragged the screen (`touchstart`, `touchmove` and `touchcancel`). Going by the same [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/#the-touchcancel-event) mentioned above, the touchcancel event should *only* run when something interferes , such as the browser interface (if I understand that correctly).

Since I was simply sliding my finger over the body, without leaving the window at all, I am really puzzled by this, so would anybody know why this is happening?

I am getting this unexpected result in **Chrome 32** and **Opera 19** for Android.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out the problem here was simply the fact the event handler didn't have an `event.preventDefault()` in it, so the original action still executed, which apparently interrupted the touch event. To fix this, simply add `e.preventDefault()` in the current event handler function to cancel the current event, and make it work as expected in Chrome and Opera too.

[**Working demo**](http://jsbin.com/popiq/2).

Comment: I just hit this issue using onpointerdown, onpointermove, and onpointerup. Finally fixed it by adding `ontouchstart = (e) => e.preventDefault()` Thanks for the pointer!