# scrollLeft wrong calculation on Firefox Android

Tags: android, jquery, firefox, mobile, scrollbar

**How it's expected to work**

I created a scollable div for a project. The position of the scrollbar is calculated width jQuery. In a desktop environment there is a visible slider. On mobile devices there is not but it's still possible to swipe left to get more content.

(It does not yet update on window resize. Reload is required.)

**Expected:** "overflow_diff" should be equal to "Scoll pos". "Percentage" should be 100 when scolled to the end.

**What works**

It works fine in Chrome and Firefox on desktop and on Chrome on Android.

**What does not work - My question**

Firefox on Android does the calculations all wrong. Strange is that it works on desktop. If it's a bug in Firefox, how do I get around it?

**Full example**

http://xn--trnell-wxa.se/scrolltest2/index.php

**HTML header**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .wrap {
        padding: 40px;
        background: #eee;
        width: 75%;
    }
    .cropped {
        overflow-x: auto;
    }
    .overflow {
        width: 300%;
        background: #ddd;
        height: 100px;
    }
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(window).ready(function($) {
        var cropped_width = $('.cropped').width();
        var overflow_width = $('.overflow').width();
        var overflow_diff = overflow_width - cropped_width;

        $( '.log' ).append( 'Overflow: ' + overflow_width + '<br>' );
        $( '.log' ).append( 'Cropped: ' + cropped_width + '<br>' );
        $( '.log' ).append( 'Overflow diff: ' + overflow_diff + '<br>' );
        $( '.log' ).append( '<div class="scrolled"></div>' );
        $( '.log' ).append( '<div class="scrolled2"></div>' );

        $( '.cropped' ).on('scroll touchmove', function() {
            var scroll_pos = $( this ).scrollLeft();
            var percentage = Math.round( scroll_pos / overflow_diff * 100 );

            $( '.log .scrolled' ).html( 'Scroll pos: ' + scroll_pos + '<br>Percentage: ' + percentage + '<br>' );
        });
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="cropped">
        <div class="overflow">Swipe to the end</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="log"></div>
```

Comment: I doubt that it's doing the math incorrectly, which means that either `$( this ).scrollLeft()` is wrong or a width has changed and `overflow_diff` is now wrong.  What happens if you recalculate overflow_diff inside the event handler and then log those two values?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should bind your event with `.on()` and use `touchmove` event too:

```
$( '.cropped' ).on('scroll touchmove', function() {
    // the code here
});
```

Comment: Maybe. However it does not change the problem that Firefox on Android calculates wrong. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

From @Joeytje50 answer [Android browsers not handling touchmove events correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21761514/android-browsers-not-handling-touchmove-events-correctly)

> Turns out the problem here was simply the fact the event handler
>   didn't have an event.preventDefault() in it, so the original action
>   still executed, which apparently interrupted the touch event. To fix
>   this, simply add e.preventDefault() in the current event handler
>   function to cancel the current event, and make it work as expected in
>   Chrome and Opera too.

Also, to check whether you use `scroll` or `touchmove` you can use the below condition,

```
// ..... your remaining code
$( '.log' ).append( '<div class="scrolled2"></div>' );

var eventName='scroll';
if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) {
    eventName = 'touchmove';
}
$( '.cropped' ).on(eventName , function(e) {
    (eventName == 'touchmove') ? e.preventDefault() : '';
    var scroll_pos = $( this ).scrollLeft();
    // your remaining code
});
```