# When I touch my JavaScript slider on mobile, I can't scroll down the page

Tags: javascript, carousel, touch-event, slide, preventdefault

I've built a slider using **pure JavaScript**. On mobile screen when I touch the slider I can only change slides but **can not scroll down the page**.
Under the hood when the slider element is touched, a *"touchstart"* event fires and the corresponding event handler function, features `event.preventDefault()` to stop scrolling the page, then when *"touchmove"* event fires, the code uses difference between first and new horizontal coordinates and CSS *left* propery to move the slider.

I made a minimal code below. Also click to [see code on online editor](https://codepen.io/vahidpouyafar/pen/BazEbgb).

```js
const slides = document.querySelector(".slides");
let posX1, posX2, dX;

slides.addEventListener("touchstart", dragStart);
slides.addEventListener("touchmove", dragAction);

function dragStart(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  posX1 = e.touches[0].clientX;
}

function dragAction(e) {
  posX2 = e.touches[0].clientX;
  dX = posX2 - posX1;
  posX1 = e.touches[0].clientX;
  slides.style.left = (slides.offsetLeft + dX) + "px";
}
```

```css
body {
  padding-bottom: 1000px;
}

.slider {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slides {
  width: 600px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
}

.slide {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.slide:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

.slide:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
}

.slide:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slides">
      <div class="slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="slide">Slide 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Hi folks, anybody here?! I'm still in need of help ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think nobody has checked my question but me, however, assuming there's a hypothetical person having the same problem as mine, I could fix that:
I figured out how to make a JavaScript slider using [this post](https://medium.com/@claudiaconceic/infinite-plain-javascript-slider-click-and-touch-events-540c8bd174f2) in which the author has used `preventDefault()` inside *"touchstart"* EventListener and I stuck to it, but the solution is to simply call `preventDefault()` method on *"touchmove"* event itself not *"touchstart"*, off course if you need (which is if the user's trying to change slides). and if user's trying to scroll the page then remove "touchend" EventListener.

```js
const slides = document.querySelector(".slides");
let posX1,
    posX2,
    posY1,
    posY2,
    dX,
    dY,
    dirDetected = false;
    
  //feature detection
  //-------------Note 1-----------//
  let passiveIfSupported = false;
  try {
    window.addEventListener("test", null, Object.defineProperty({}, "passive", {
      get: function() {passiveIfSupported = {passive: false};}
    }));
  } catch(err) {}

slides.addEventListener("touchstart", dragStart, passiveIfSupported);
slides.addEventListener("touchmove", dragAction, passiveIfSupported);
slides.addEventListener("touchend", dragEnd, false);

function dragStart(e) {
  posX1 = e.touches[0].clientX;
  posY1 = e.touches[0].clientY;
}

function dragAction(e) {
  //-------------Note 2-----------//
  e.preventDefault();
  
  posX2 = e.touches[0].clientX;
  posY2 = e.touches[0].clientY;
  dX = posX2 - posX1;
  posX1 = e.touches[0].clientX;
  dY = posY2 - posY1;
  
  if (!dirDetected) {
    if (Math.abs(dY) > Math.abs(dX)) {
      slides.removeEventListener("touchmove", dragAction, passiveIfSupported);
      return;
    }
    dirDetected = true;
  }
    
  slides.style.left = (slides.offsetLeft + dX) + "px";
}

  function dragEnd() {
    if (!dirDetected) {
      slides.addEventListener("touchmove", dragAction, passiveIfSupported);
    }
    dirDetected = false;
  }
```

```css
body {
  padding-bottom: 1000px;
}

.slider {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slides {
  width: 600px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
}

.slide {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.slide:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

.slide:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
}

.slide:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slides">
      <div class="slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="slide">Slide 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Note 1. (addEventListener's third parameter)**: note the third parameter of `addEventListener()` method. there's something I realized in my searches from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49590237/14637348). I'm going to use `preventDefault()` inside *"touchmove"* EventListener but in some versions of Chrome and Firefox for *"touchstart"* and *"touchmove"* events if you don't specify passive property of options object (the third parameter of `addEventListener()`) the default value would be set to true and this doesn't let the EventListener to call `preventDefault()` so you have to set the third parameter to `{passive: false}` but if the browser loading your script is an old one which requires a third boolean parameter for `addEventListener()` then you need to provide a boolean value not object. So you can use [feature detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Improving_scrolling_performance_with_passive_listeners) to provide an appropraite parameter.

**Note 2. Firefox and chrom android handle "touchmove" preventDefault() differently:** Here's another point I found [(from this question)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21761514/14637348), if you run the above code on Chrome Android it works well, you can scroll the page or change slides but on Firefox Android you can't scroll. Actually I think it's a Chrome's fault because according to [Specs for *"touchmove"* event](https://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/#the-touchmove-event) if the first *"touchmove"* event is prevented the subsequent *"touchmove"* events bound to the same touch point are prevented and in the code above at the very first line of *"touchmove"* event handler function I used `preventDefault()` so I need to call it after the if block so ensure default behaviour is prevented when needed.

```js
const slides = document.querySelector(".slides");
let posX1,
    posX2,
    posY1,
    posY2,
    dX,
    dY,
    dirDetected = false;
    
  //feature detection
  let passiveIfSupported = false;
  try {
    window.addEventListener("test", null, Object.defineProperty({}, "passive", {
      get: function() {passiveIfSupported = {passive: false};}
    }));
  } catch(err) {}

slides.addEventListener("touchstart", dragStart, passiveIfSupported);
slides.addEventListener("touchmove", dragAction, passiveIfSupported);
slides.addEventListener("touchend", dragEnd, false);

function dragStart(e) {
  posX1 = e.touches[0].clientX;
  posY1 = e.touches[0].clientY;
}

function dragAction(e) {
  posX2 = e.touches[0].clientX;
  posY2 = e.touches[0].clientY;
  dX = posX2 - posX1;
  posX1 = e.touches[0].clientX;
  dY = posY2 - posY1;
  
  if (!dirDetected) {
    if (Math.abs(dY) > Math.abs(dX)) {
      slides.removeEventListener("touchmove", dragAction, passiveIfSupported);
      return;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  
  dirDetected = true;
  slides.style.left = (slides.offsetLeft + dX) + "px";
}

  function dragEnd() {
    if (!dirDetected) {
      slides.addEventListener("touchmove", dragAction, passiveIfSupported);
    }
    dirDetected = false;
  }
```

```css
body {
  padding-bottom: 1000px;
}

.slider {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slides {
  width: 600px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
}

.slide {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.slide:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

.slide:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
}

.slide:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slides">
      <div class="slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="slide">Slide 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```